Write RTL to CSV file using C#
I am trying to write a function that receives a DataTable and writes the data from it into a csv file, The function works, but I want the file content to be displayed in Right-to-Left (RTL)..
I tried adding culture info, utf8 but it didn't work and I didn't find any support how can I do it?
that's my code
private static async Task SaveCsvFile(DataTable dt, FileInfo file)
{
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("he-IL");
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(file.FullName, false, Encoding.UTF8);
        using var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer, cultureInfo);

        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
        }
        await csv.NextRecordAsync();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                csv.WriteField(row[i]);
            }
            await csv.NextRecordAsync();
        }
}


Unfortunately, if you're using a third party library such as CsvHelper, then contact the developer for assistance. It appears that the developer has stated on the website that users should post on SO for issues regarding the use of his/her/their product. SO is not free technical support for other peoples' products. I would steer clear of any product that states that you should contact someone else for technical support of their product. Alternatively, you may wish to read through the source code.

Since a .csv file is just a comma-delimited text file, all you really need is File.WriteAllLines, File.WriteAllText, or FileStream.

I want the file content to be displayed in Right-to-Left (RTL).. -- how are you displaying the file contents?  The Unicode bidirectional display algorithm is a rendering algorithm: It is important to understand from the outset that, in all major web browsers, the order of characters in memory (logical) is not the same as the order in which they are displayed (visual).  So your CSV contents will not be right-to-left, instead your display tool must render in right-to-left.

I don't believe this is a CsvHelper issue, but rather a display issue.  CsvHelper uses CultureInfo to determine things like the cultural delimiter to use and how to display dates and numbers.  It then uses StreamWriter to do the actual writing to the file, which should default to UTF8.  The file doesn't understand "Left to Right" vs "Right to Left".  It just understands the start of the file, some text, and the end of the file. The display of the file would be handled be the software that is being used to view the file.
I did notice when I was looking at this answer to Write to a txt file right to left that the Hebrew that showed in my C# editor was backwards of what the output file shows in a text editor.
string hebrew = @"מספרים רצים מימין לשמאל ?";
var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test_heb.txt");
file.WriteLine(hebrew);
file.Close();

Hebrew text is flipped depending on what editor I was using to view the text.

